# Types of a function

Tags: haskell, types

I saw on a Haskell tutorial this function:

```
factorial :: (Integral a) => a -> a
```

My question is why should I use that instead of this:

```
factorial :: Int->Int
```

It's because with the first one we can use every type of numbers and in the second one we can only use an `Int`?

Comment: Yes. That's it.

Comment: You may want to use `Integer` at least

Comment: A detail: that type means you can use any type of *integer* numbers (that is, any type which is an instance of `Integer`). For instance, `factorial 0.5` won't work.

Answer (score 2):

*This answer is a mashup of the comments to the question.*

Your interpretation is correct, except for one detail: that type means you can use any type of *integer* numbers (that is, any type which is an instance of `Integer`). For instance, `factorial 0.5` won't work, as expected for a factorial function.

Comment: So if i put (Num a) instead of (Integral a) factorial 0.5 will work?

Comment: @paulo_ferreira, when you do that, and test it, what happens? Can you figure out why?